# Santa's Surprise Spell Damage on storages

Tags: clash-of-clans

Would Santa's Surprise Spell do any damage to any *storages*? Or are they not affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spells will never do damage to storages due a previous update.

As seen in this [Clash of Clans YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0J3S5xnsJA) on a [Yahoo article](http://sports.yahoo.com/news/clash-clans-clashmas-brings-santas-143858835.html), the storages are still protected from Santa's Surprise Spell:

[image]